# str_getcsv example

Tags: php, csv

I want to parse a comma separated value string into an array. I want to try the `str_getcsv()` php function but I can't find any good examples on how to use it.

For example I have an input where users submit tags for programming languages (php, js, jquery, etc), like the "tags" input in stackoverflow when you submit a question.

How would I turn an input with example `value="php, js, jquery"` into an array using str_getcsv?

Comment: why don't you use just explode function?

Comment: maybe I did get you wrong, but `$myArray = str_getcsv($value);` should do?

Comment: @heximal: Where would be the advantage of doing so?

Comment: @heximal, I am assuming that str_getcsv is more ideal for my case since it's for CSV

Comment: @heximal: explode will not take into account text with a comma contained with parentheses.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Its true that the spec at https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php doesn't include a standard example, but the user-submitted notes do a decent job of covering it. If this is a form input:

```
$val = $_POST['value'];
$data = str_getcsv($val);
```

`$data` is now an array with the values. Try it and see if you have any other issues.

Answer (score 9):

I think you should maybe look at [explode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) for this task.

```
 $values  = "php, js, jquery";
 $items = explode(",", $values);

 // Would give you an array:
 echo $items[0];  // would be php
 echo $items[1];  // would be js
 echo $items[2];  // would be jquery
```

This would probably more efficient than str_getcsv();

Note that you would need to use trim() to remove possible whitespace befores and after item values.

**UPDATE:**

I hadn't seen str_getcsv before, but read this quote on the manpage that would make it seem a worthwhile candidate:

> Why not use explode() instead of str_getcsv() to parse rows? 
>   Because explode() would not treat possible enclosured parts of 
>   string or escaped characters correctly.

Comment: Thanks +1 for example. Explode is a good function but str_getcsv seems to trim whitespace automatically. I'm in a dilemma between the 2.

Answer (score 3):

For simplicity and readability, I typically find myself using just explode(), only adding in str_getcsv() if the following two conditions are met: 1) the primary delimiter is also used within the data itself; 2) the token that I'm trying to use as the main delimiter is enclosed by another distinct character.

For example, a basic parser for a CSV file:

```
$filename = $argv[1];
if (empty($filename)) { echo "Input file required\n"; exit; }
$AccountsArray = explode("\n", file_get_contents($filename));
```

As long as each of the elements of $AccountsArray doesn't embed a "," within the data itself, this will work perfectly and is straightforward and easy to follow:

```
foreach ($AccountsArray as $entry) {
    $acctArr = explode(",", $entry);
}
```

However, often the data will contain the delimiter, at which point an enclosing token (a " in this example) has to be present. If so, then I switch to str_getcsv() like so:

```
foreach ($AccountsArray as $entry) {
    $acctArr = str_getcsv($entry, ",", "\""); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing! That is good when getting data from a file.

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer. It is clear and shows how to use str_getcsv() in place of explode() which is what I was using.

Answer (score 0):

```
//get the csv
$csvFile = file_get_contents('test.csv');
//separate each line
$csv = explode("\n",$csvFile);

foreach ($csv as $csvLine) {

    //separet each fields
    $linkToInsert = explode(",",$csvLine);
    //echo what you need
    //$linkToInsert[0] would be the first field, $linkToInsert[1] second field, etc
    echo '• ' . $linkToInsert[1] . '<br>';
}
```

Comment: This generally won’t work. What if a field includes a newline? or a comma?

Comment: in that case I think you could "filter" out or remove the new lines and any other stuff you don't want with a str_replace just before the explode.

Comment: Example:
"Field 1","Field 2","Field with a, comma","Field 4"
Do you remove the comma inside Field 3? How? And maybe the comma was here for a reason?

Comment: in that case it would depend on how the csv filewas created. Normally when I create a csv file I choose a field delimiter like a " -> so it would give "field 1","field 2",etc... if it's not a csv file, why you wan to use the function str_getcsv() ?

Comment: CSV means “comma separated value” and lots of apps can read or write the format.
WIWSV (“whatever I want separated values”) is perfectly ok for some uses, but you won’t be able to read it or write it with, for example, Excel.

Answer (score 0):

The code is quite simple, using the `Str_getcsv` function, we will go 
through each line of the CSV file "images.csv" that is located in the 
same directory as our script.

NOTE: Functions used are compatible with versions of PHP >= 5.3.0

```
//First, reading the CSV file

$csvFile = file('file.csv');

foreach ($csvFile as $line) {
    $url = str_getcsv($line);

    $ch = curl_init($url[0]);

    $name = basename($url[0]);

    if (!file_exists('directory/' . $name)) {
        $fp = fopen('directory/' . $name, 'wb');
    }

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    fclose($fp);         
}
```