# How to write a specific regular expression?

Tags: php, regex

I have the following text:

```
"text tutorial" tutorial tipps tricks diy fashion "fashion style"
```

No I want to have a regular expression which splits the text above to single keywords. All the keywords which a in quotes should be fined as a single keyword.

The output of the regular expression should be this:

1. text tutorial
2. tutorial
3. tipps
4. tricks
5. diy
6. fashion
7. fashion style

Thanks.

Comment: Or a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6169235/str-getcsv-example.

Comment: You actually can do it with regular expressions: [**`((?:"[^"]+"|\b\w+\b))`**](https://regex101.com/r/tF4sK7/1)

Answer (score 0):

use a `str_getcsv()`, Try:

```
str_getcsv($text, ' ')
```

Output of `str_getcsv()`;

```
Array
(
    [0] => text tutorial
    [1] => tutorial
    [2] => tipps
    [3] => tricks
    [4] => diy
    [5] => fashion
    [6] => fashion style
)
```

Comment: Your regex code does not return the expected results. `str_getcsv()` is the best method here.